# Integration testing Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, android-testing

I'm new to testing on Android. I see a lot of articles and tutorial about unit testing and with end-to-end testing (with espresso). It's ok. But what about integration testing ?

For the exemple, I use Firebase Database for my app. Is it possible to do this kind of test in the instrumentation test :

```
@Test
public void tryFirebaseTest() throws FieldRequiredException, InvalidPhoneException, InvalidEmailException, InterruptedException {

    UserManager userManager = new UserManager(new FIRUserStorage(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()));
    userManager.createUser("test@test.com", "test", "+4778787", "", new CreateUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void userCreated(User user) {
            assertNotNull(user);
        }

        @Override
        public void userExistError() {
            fail();
        }

        @Override
        public void userDatabaseError(String errorMessage) {
            fail();
        }
 });

}
```

In this case, the test don't get in the callback.

Comment: In such cases you should also use the Espresso.

Answer (score -1):

For integration testing a Firebase app, you currently have two options:

1. Run [local-firebase](https://github.com/urish/firebase-server) server, as discussed in [this article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html), and write integration tests in jUnit/TestNG or whatever automation framework you like.
2. Write Espresso tests to test the complete integration

There are a few tools to help with the mocking like [fingular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fingular), but you'll have to play with it a bit to see what kind of mileage you'll get out per your project and to what extent you integration test.